# AutoLayout Constrains Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

**I have a simple UIView Controller, Navigation Bar and UITextView with some text inside!**

- I just reset is to suggested constraints and it looks great on a
  preview
- BUT when I run simulator `UITextView` start scrolling from the middle
  not from top where text starts!!! it just driven me crazy!!!
- I have tried to setup constrains manually too and I seeing great
  results on preview screen But on simulator the same issue, starts
  from de middle SOS please!

Here are links to the images ("HISTORIA" IS A TOP WORD BUT NOT ON SIMULATOR) !

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9tavqnotrqogmg/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-06%20at%2022.00.26.png?dl=0)

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phtnzx0bzx9q1rk/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-06%20at%2021.59.40.png?dl=0)

Comment: You will need to show either the code used to add the constraints or the nib file in order for anyone to actually help. What you have posted here is a rant, not an answer.

Comment: 1) Your first step is not to panic but to remain calm 2) Run your app in the simulator and use the `View Debugger` to examine the constraints live. This will allow you to see what they are actually doing and the fix may then become immediately obvious. This is why Apple includes the `View Debugger` (link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) 3) If after investigation you don't understand what is happening then you post a question on SO with the expected outcome, the actual outcome and images of the constraints in IB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP's has posted a rant not a question. OP has also not included any information that could be used to try to fix the problem.

Comment: There is no code to show i'm using autolayout on storyboard! I can't post images so i can't include more info that i'm already wrote!!! I know about View Debugger not helping!!!

Comment: Even someone with not enough rep can post images. Just stick them onto Dropbox and put a link to them. Dropbox is free. Screenshots can be grabbed with CMD-SHIFT-3 (or 4).

Comment: OK Thanks! I already understand the problem was contentView OffSet not UITextView!!! OK i just offset the content inside UITextView! BUT still not understand why that OffSet happens and why it not visible on a preview????

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've set up the constraints in a way that the UITextView grows as you enter more text into it. You should probably assign more explicit size constraints instead of using "Reset to Suggested Constraints".

Try assigning a top,bottom,leading and trailing constraint to the superview. There are many ways to do this, but the easiest to explain on SO is to use the toolbar: **Editor>Pin>Leading/Trailing/TopBottom Space to Superview**

Comment: Sorry, looking at your answer, I realize I misunderstood your problem. Glad you worked it out in the end!

Answer (score 0):

DONE

```
@IBOutlet weak var textContent: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        textContent.scrollsToTop = true
        var contentHeight = textContent.contentSize.height
        var offSet = textContent.contentOffset.x
        var contentOffset = contentHeight - offSet
        textContent.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -contentOffset)
    }
```